# Spring mvc resocures mapping in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I am having an strange problem with Google Appengine and Spring mvc resources mapping

Here is my spring mvc resources mapping xml content

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/META-INF/static/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/META-INF/static/css/" />
```

In my template file, i am referencing my css file as

```
<link href="/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

where mystyle.css is located at /META-INF/static/css/mystyle.css in war folder.

Now the problem is when running application, I am getting an NumberFormatException with warning

Warning: /css/mystyle.css

And css doesn't load, but the strange thing is when I refresh again it sometime works without exception and warning and sometime it does not.

This problem doesn't exists when i run the app outside GAE ie I ran on tomcat server and it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine has its own static file mapping that you can use in appengine-web.xml file.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files